# React-redux app is not refreshing stored with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm using React JS for my web app.

It gets data from the API using Redux and Axios.

When I enter to some profile page in app, It gets data from the API and renders the page.

The problem is, when I go to another profile, it first opens the page with previous profile's data, then after 2-3 seconds the information changes into the newly fetched data.

In some components the change does not happen and they show previous information. Only after 2-3 refreshes you see the change.

Almost all of my API interaction functions are async functions.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to React, I don't know what part of code to paste here for more details. Have no clue what this issue might be connected with.

Comment: Add the most important thing: code

Comment: @Max I have no idea which part of the code is "in charge" for this issue. Is it the storage part that's in redux?

Comment: Do you track "loading" state when you do a request? Because seems like you're not

Comment: Then you should debug your code to narrow down the problem. The redux devtools might also help. Without any code this is almost impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 triggers of going to a new profile page and calling fetch are called together. You need to separate them.
**Option 1:**
   Show new page, then loading, then fetched profile.
**Option 2:**
   Show loading, wait for the fetch to succeed, then switch.